# Is there a way to disable the integrated webcam without disabling USB webcams?

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

There are a number of documented ways to disable the integrated webcam out there. In particular, I have been using the approach that makes a number of system files unreadable:

```
sudo chmod a-r /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/VDC.plugin/Contents/MacOS/VDC
sudo chmod a-r /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaIOServicesPrivate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AVC.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AVC
sudo chmod a-r /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeUSBVDCDigitizer                     
sudo chmod a-r /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera                     
sudo chmod a-r /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/FCP-DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera
```

The problem I am having is that this approach seems to clobber USB cams as well.

Is there an approach whereby I can render the integrated cam undetectable, but USB cams still work?

Comment: put a piece of black electrical over the lens 

Comment: that doesn't prevent applications from detecting it, which is what I need.